# SetWindowDisplayAffinity fails with error "Access denied"

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I am using jna.extra.User32Extra library in java to find a window and change the windowdisplayaffinity value.
But it is returning "ACCESS DENIED" error code.

```
HWND top= target.findWindow("WindowTitle");
System.err.println(User32Extra.INSTANCE.SetWindowDisplayAffinity(top, 0));
System.err.println(Native.getLastError());
```

The following code gives "false" and error code "5"(ACCESS DENIED).

Do I need any extra permissions? What is the reason for that error?

Comment: Please check the [MSDN entry for SetWindowDisplayAffinity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375340(v=vs.85).aspx). In particular, look at some of the community addition information at the bottom.

Comment: I have seen that already but I didn't understand how to inject thread into the target process..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SetWindowDisplayAffinity` can only be used on a window owned by the calling process. Hence the error. The documentation says:

> This feature enables applications to protect their own onscreen window content from being captured or copied through a specific set of public operating system features and APIs.

The feature would be rendered useless if another application could so readily override the target application's choice.

Comment: How can we set **setWindowDisplayAffinity** for a flex application while creating. Is there any ways to do that? @david-heffernan